# I cannot find the error

Tags: java

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/read_a_textfile_in_java.html) and I have been trying to get this working for two days now. I get this error message when compiling FileData.

```
FileData.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
          ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
          ^
   symbol:   class ReadFile
   location: class FileData

FileData.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
          ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
                              ^
   symbol:   class ReadFile
   location: class FileData
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The code follows:

```
package textfiles;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FileData
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String file_name = "C:/test.txt";

        try
        {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

            int i;
            for (i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );

        }

    }
}


package textfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadFile
{

    private String path;

    public ReadFile (String file_path) //ReadFile Method
    {
        path = file_path;
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException //OpenFile method
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int numberOfLines = readLine();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        int i;

        for (i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) 
        {
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }

        textReader.close();
        return textData;
    }

    int readLine() throws IOException //readLines Method
    {
        FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

        String aLines;
        int numberOfLines = 0;

        while ((aLines = bf.readLine()) !=null) 
        {
            numberOfLines++;
        }
        bf.close();

        return numberOfLines;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are they in different files? ie. FileData.java and ReadFile.java. If not, that's the first step to do.

Comment: R u using cmd or terminal or an IDE like netbeans, eclipse? Also the code has to be in two different files named as that of class i.e. "FileData.java" and "ReadFile.java" inside a package named "textfiles"

Comment: while compiling ur source code from cmd/terminal u have to be outside the package. try running this compile command: javac textfiles\*.java

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `JAVA COMPILER` is looking for `CLASS FILE` {ReadFile.class} inside the folder textfiles so follow this to get compile,

1--> compile the ReadFile using this

```
javac -d . ReadFile.java
```

2--> compile the FileData  using this

```
javac -d . FileData.java
```

NOTE: The purpose of this

> -d

is it will create appropriate packages during compilation.